# Linux VirtualBox with Win7 guest network wireless issue

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Laptop with Linux Mint 13 host with Win7 Guest. 2 network adaptors configured, 1 NAT and 1 Bridged. Guest will only see internet if network cable plugged into laptop. Won't see internet if laptop is on either Wireless or Mobile Broadband.

Have disabled IPV6 in guests network adaptor properties (from a VB forum).

Any ideas how to get the guest to see the internet when the host is using non-wired connections?  This used to work a few months ago but maybe VB has updated something.

Comment: Try disabling the bridged virtual adapter and verify the guest can access the internet when wired and wireless through the NAT adapter.

Comment: Did what you suggested, no access through the NAT only adaptor on wireless or cable.  Don't understand why question was marked down though. I spent all morning trying to get this working and only called for help when all other options exhausted. When the answer is found, it will be posted here and will help others.

Comment: The down vote was probably due to the fact your issue has nothing to do (directly) with programming - it currently has two votes to close it as off-topic and move it to SuperUser.com - Regardless, if your guest doesn't have internet access with just the NAT adapter, you have bigger problems with your virtualization stack. Do you have the same problem with a fresh installation / booting a LiveCD as a guest configured with just a single virtual adapter configured for NAT?

Comment: Sorted it. The Virtual Adapter setting in VB had to have it's "Attached to" name set to wlan0. So in the end I have a set up with 2 adaptors, one NAT and one Bridged set to wlan0. Didn't realise this site was for pure programming issues. Will use the sister site in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a simple solution to the connectivity problem in Virtualbox:

1. Set the **Network setting to NAT** in Virtualbox settings for the Virtual/Guest Machine
2. After booting into the virtual/guest machine, go to Network Adapter Properties,
   and insert the following **DNS server addresses**:
   **208.67.222.222

   208.67.220.220**
   (OpenDNS configuration)
3. Now full internet connectivity is established.